# After downgrade of Nvidia driver cannot start Nvidia Settings in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I have some issues with Nvidia Settings and can't get what's the problem? I dowgraded my recommended Nvidia driver to older version and everything seems to be fine the resolution and video, so on, I just can't start Nvidia Settings using Terminal, don't know why? Nvidia present at StartUp Applications and whatever... Here's some details from Terminal:

```
Kernel driver in use: nvidia

jockey-text -l
xorg:nvidia_173_updates - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (Proprietary, Enabled, In use)

xorg:nvidia_304 - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)

xorg:nvidia_304_updates - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)

sudo nvidia-xconfig

WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file.

New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
```

after this I rebooted the system Xorg.conf seems to be present now in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but if I run in Terminal `nvidia-settings` still says: `command not found` I also ran `gksudo nvidia-settings` as a root but after all still says: `command not found` I've read similar posts to this, but still confused.

Comment: Vladdy, thank you for providing us with this information. On AskUbuntu, we prefer the following style: post your comment as an answer, and accept this answer as the solution for your question. You can remove the 'SOLVED' part in the question's title: as soon as you accept your own question, there will be a green dot before your question to show that it is solved.

Comment: ok, got it... only it says I can accept it in 2 days.

Comment: Yes, that's something built-in in AskUbuntu. Come back in a couple of days and you'll be able to hit the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem SOLVED! thanks anyways to those who checked or tried to reply to this post. The problem was in that I had to reinstall Nvidia Settings as the older Nvidia drivers are not compatible with `X server` on Ubuntu 12.04 and up. But it's ok now I have what I wanted old good Nvidia-173.14.37 video card works at best.